# Reading a text file as a input and then writing text files with the data in 2D matrices as output

Tags: fortran90, fortran77

I am the real novice in FORTRAN90, of course in any other programming language.
However, I need to make a program for my work.
So I am asking any comment from anybody.
Thanks in advance.

From now on, I will explain my problem.
The original data is just following as;

```
15 1r 2 1r 70 22r 2 2r 15 1r 2 1r 8 8r 15 1 3r
```

This is could be written again in another way like below;

```
15 15 2 2 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 2 2 2 15 15 2 2 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 15 1 1 1 1
```

So the total number of data elements in the above example can be counted 48.
The total number of the original data is `12,113,640`.
And then the original data was made of 220(z) slices of `322(x) x 171(y)`.
Each slices has 55,062 of elements.

If it is possible, just like the way of count of the element number, the program count by 55,062 elements and then make output file(txt) and then totally 220 slices of the data should be 2D array.

So I have to extract 220 slices from the one whole data file. And also the data should be 2D array in each slice.

Comment: What does this have to do with C or C++?

Comment: Unfortunately your input file can't be interpreted without some looking ahead, when you read an integer such as `15` the file doesn't guarantee that what comes next is either a repetition count or the next integer value.  Do you have any control over the design and contents of that file ?  And what have you written so far ?  It's not terrifically difficult to read that input, but I'm too lazy to write it all for you, might help you to get your code right.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The above numbers are just a number in a text file. And also totally 12,113,640 numbers in the text file in the same way of the above description. So I just thought a FORTRAN program can count the numbers of the data in one original text file and then, when the sum of counts is 55,062, if an output file as a text file in 2D array having the size of 322 by 171. Finally if 220 of output file can be made, it would be very nice.

Comment: `1r` is not a number in a text file, `1` is, but `r` isn't.

Comment: Sorry for annoying you. Yes, you are right. I was wrong to say the data form exactly because of my ignorance. Sorry about that. Because of that, the text file seems to be CHARACTER in Fortran. But I do not know how to do in detail. If it would be okay with you, please let me give some advice. Thanks!

Comment: My advice is to search the web for a basic Fortran tutorial (you'll find approximately 1 million hits) and to start learning.  Then, when you have a program you need help with, come back to SO.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I am reading a Fortran tutorial searched on the web from this morning. But I feel some difficulty to get some sense of programming. In addition, solution of my question is now a little bit urgently required. So I have no choice but to vexing you. I am really sorry. After learning by myself, then I will come back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this - I assume you know how to read lines from the file

```
program main
   character(len=120):: compressed
   character ch
   integer value, rval, repeat, ix, complen

   ! Pretend this is the line read from the file
   compressed = '15 1r 2 1r 70 22r 2 2r 15 1r 2 1r 8 8r 15 1 3r'

   complen = len(trim(compressed))
   ix = 1
   do while (ix .lt. complen)
      ! Skip spaces
      do
         ch = compressed(ix:ix)
         if (ch .ne. ' ') exit
         ix = ix + 1
      end do

      ! Extract the number
      value = 0
      do
         ch = compressed(ix:ix)
         if (ch .ge. '0' .and. ch .le. '9') then
            value = value * 10 + ichar(ch) - ichar('0')
         else
            exit
         end if
         ix = ix + 1
         if (ix .gt. complen) exit
      end do

      ! is it a repeater
      repeat = 1
      if (ch .eq. 'r') then
         ! reduce by 1 since one has already been printed
         repeat = value  - 1
         ix = ix + 1
      else
         rval = value
      end if

      ! assume there won't be more than 100 repeats
      write(*, '(100I3)', advance='no') (rval, ii = 1, repeat)
   end do
   stop
end program
```